# C++. Object is instantiated with wrong constructor?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

I'm getting a weird error about there being no matching function for a function I'm not even calling. Here's the error:

`BinarySearchTree.h:18:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘BinaryTree<int>::BinaryTree()’
 BinarySearchTree<T>::BinarySearchTree(T elem)`

Obviously it's not finding that function because I don't have it in there. I don't have it in there because it's pretty pointless to instantiate a totally empty Binary Tree (or at least it seems that way to me). I also realize that there are libraries out there with these data structures in them. I'm just doing this to help with learning the material in my Data Structures class as well as to learn more about C++, which up until recently I've only been using as "C with classes." I can't understand why the compiler is asking me for that constructor if I don't want to have it in there.

Here's the source file. I'm not instantiating the tree with the default constructor, which is what confuses me so much. Also, the preorder method works perfectly in the base class, so it should work with the derived one (I'm only making a derived class to add methods that are specific to a binary search tree, but it's still a binary tree).

```
#include "../headers/BinarySearchTree.h"
#include <cstdio>

void print_int_node(BTreeNode<int>* tgt)
{
    printf("%d, ", tgt->getElement());
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    BinarySearchTree<int> myTree(5);

    printf("Pre-order: \n");
    myTree.preorder(myTree.root, print_int_node);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the classes I'm using:

BinarySearchTree.h:

```
#ifndef _BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_H_
#define _BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_H_

#include "BinaryTree.h"

template <typename T>
class BinarySearchTree : public BinaryTree<T> {
    void _add(BTreeNode<T>*, T elem);

    public:
        BinarySearchTree(T);

        void add(T);
};

template <typename T>
BinarySearchTree<T>::BinarySearchTree(T elem)
{
    this->root = new BTreeNode<T>(elem);
}

template <typename T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::add(T elem)
{

}

/***PRIVATE HELPER FUNCTIONS***/
template <typename T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::_add(BTreeNode<T>* n, T elem)
{
    if(elem >= n->getElement()){
        if(n->getRightChild() != NULL){
            _add(n->getRightChild(), elem);
        }else{
            n->setRightChild(new BTreeNode<T>(elem));
        }
    }else{
        if(n->getLeftChild() != NULL){
            _add(n->getLeftChild(), elem);
        }else{
            n->setLeftChild(new BTreeNode<T>(elem));
        }
    }
}

#endif //_BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_H_
```

BinaryTree.h:

```
#ifndef _BINARY_TREE_H_
#define _BINARY_TREE_H_

#include "BTreeNode.h"

template <typename T>
class BinaryTree {
    public:
        BTreeNode<T>* root;

        BinaryTree(T);

        //traversals
        void preorder(BTreeNode<T>*, void (*func)(BTreeNode<T>*));
        void inorder(BTreeNode<T>*, void (*func)(BTreeNode<T>*));
        void postorder(BTreeNode<T>*, void (*func)(BTreeNode<T>*));
};

template <typename T>
BinaryTree<T>::BinaryTree(T elem)
{
    root = new BTreeNode<T>(elem);
}

template <typename T>
void BinaryTree<T>::preorder(BTreeNode<T>* node, void (*func)(BTreeNode<T>*))
{
    if(node == NULL)
        return;

    func(node);
    preorder(node->getLeftChild(), func);
    preorder(node->getRightChild(), func);
}

template <typename T>
void BinaryTree<T>::inorder(BTreeNode<T>* node, void (*func)(BTreeNode<T>*))
{
    if(node == NULL)
        return;

    inorder(node->getLeftChild(), func);
    func(node);
    inorder(node->getRightChild(), func);
}

template <typename T>
void BinaryTree<T>::postorder(BTreeNode<T>* node, void (*func)(BTreeNode<T>*))
{
    if(node == NULL)
        return;

    postorder(node->getLeftChild(), func);
    postorder(node->getRightChild(), func);
    func(node);
}
#endif //_BINARY_TREE_H_
```

BTreeNode.h:

```
#ifndef _B_TREE_NODE_H_
#define _B_TREE_NODE_H_

#define NULL 0

template <typename T>
class BTreeNode {
    T element;
    BTreeNode<T>* left;
    BTreeNode<T>* right;

    public:
        BTreeNode(T);
        BTreeNode(T, BTreeNode<T>*, BTreeNode<T>*);
        ~BTreeNode();

        T getElement();
        BTreeNode<T>* getLeftChild();
        BTreeNode<T>* getRightChild();

        void setElement(T elem);
        BTreeNode<T>* setLeftChild(BTreeNode<T>*);
        BTreeNode<T>* setRightChild(BTreeNode<T>*);
};

template <typename T>
BTreeNode<T>::BTreeNode(T elem)
{
    element = elem;
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
}

template <typename T>
BTreeNode<T>::BTreeNode(T elem, BTreeNode<T>* l, BTreeNode<T>* r)
{
    element = elem;
    left = l;
    right = r;
}

template <typename T>
BTreeNode<T>::~BTreeNode<T>()
{
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
}

template <typename T>
T BTreeNode<T>::getElement()
{
    return element;
}

template <typename T>
BTreeNode<T>* BTreeNode<T>::getLeftChild()
{
    return left;
}

template <typename T>
BTreeNode<T>* BTreeNode<T>::getRightChild()
{
    return right;
}

template <typename T>
void BTreeNode<T>::setElement(T elem)
{
    element = elem;
}

template <typename T>
BTreeNode<T>* BTreeNode<T>::setLeftChild(BTreeNode<T>* l)
{
    left = l;
    return left;
}

template <typename T>
BTreeNode<T>* BTreeNode<T>::setRightChild(BTreeNode<T>* r)
{
    right = r;
    return right;
}
#endif //_B_TREE_NODE_H_
```

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_H_`, `_BINARY_TREE_H_`, `_B_TREE_NODE_H_`) are reserved to the implementation (the compiler and its headers). Don't use them.

Comment: `#define NULL 0` is a horrible thing to put anywhere, especially a header. `NULL` is already a macro in many standard headers.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you are calling it.

In your constructor on `BinarySearchTree`:

```
template <typename T>
BinarySearchTree<T>::BinarySearchTree(T elem)
{
    this->root = new BTreeNode<T>(elem);
}
```

You aren't making an explicit call to the parent class's constructor, so it's using the default. You need to do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
BinarySearchTree<T>::BinarySearchTree(T elem) : BinaryTree(elem)
{
    this->root = new BTreeNode<T>(elem);
}
```

Use your initializer list!

As a side note, this will also cause you to leak memory, because both constructors initialize the member `root` with their own copy of `new BTreeNode...`

You should also read up on how constructors work in the inheritance case.

Comment: Might as well have both in there.

Comment: Why would there be two initializations if I'm only instantiating one object?

Comment: You're inheriting from `BinaryTree` with `BinarySearchTree`. Both constructors are called.

Comment: @Hugo All constructors in the inheritance tree are each called from the top down. Destructors are each called from the bottom up.

Comment: Oh that's right. So then I guess the way to keep two pointers to root from being created would be to just use the constructor inherited from the base class?

Comment: Just initialize the pointer in the class that's responsible for it. `root` should probably be private in `BinaryTree` anyway. If it were, you wouldn't have this problem in the first place, as `BinarySearchTree` wouldn't be able to touch `root` directly.

Comment: The reason root is public is that in order to add nodes to the BinaryTree object the user needs to access it directly. I did this so that the user could have direct control over how the tree is structured. Because BinarySearchTree is a child of BinaryTree, it has this feature as well even though it doesn't need it (nodes are added in a specific way). But I figured out how to do it. Everything works now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Class BinaryTree has no default constructor that is called from the constructor of BinarySearchTree because BinaryTree is a base class of BinarySearchTree.